# Auto resize panel after content pane is hide

Tags: javascript, layout, dojo

This does not work for me, my case (Dojo 1.7):

```
function showWidthElm(elm_div_zone_id,show) {

var toggler = new dojo.fx.Toggler({
    node: "leftAccordionElm"+elm_div_zone_id
});

if(show==true){
    toggler.show();
    dijit.byId("center_panel_elm").resize();
}
else{
    toggler.hide();
    dijit.byId("center_panel_elm").resize();
}
```

}

after close action i need to hide left accordion and show only centre region (dijitBorderContainer-child). Its hide good but don't resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, combine show() and hide() with style and resize:

```
    function showWidthElm(elm_div_zone_id,show) {

    var toggler = new dojo.fx.Toggler({
        node: "leftAccordionElm"+elm_div_zone_id
    });

    var borderContainer = dijit.byId('leftAccordionElm'+elm_div_zone_id);
    var borderContainer2 = dijit.byId('center_panel_elm');
    var borderContainer3 = dijit.byId('center_panel_tab_cont');

    if(show==true){
        toggler.show();
        dojo.setStyle(borderContainer.domNode, 'width','280px');
        dojo.setStyle(borderContainer2.domNode, 'width','80%');
        borderContainer3.resize();
    }
    else{
        toggler.hide();
        dojo.setStyle(borderContainer.domNode, 'width','0px');
        dojo.setStyle(borderContainer2.domNode, 'width','100%');
        borderContainer3.resize();
    }
}
```